# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcode

Every time I try to compile for device (arm7) in Xcode 4, I get this error. Due to my inexperience in programming I have no idea how to fix it.

```
CompileC /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.o Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s normal armv7 assembler-with-cpp com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd "/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy"
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x assembler-with-cpp -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -iquote /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/cannonboy-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/cannonboy-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/cannonboy-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/cannonboy-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Products/include -I/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Products -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.d -c "/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s" -o /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dvjqpowuaruycvahisaknogdkwbr/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.o

/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:8:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:8:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 48 (0).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:18:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:18:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 48 (0).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:36:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:36:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 48 (0).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:44:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:44:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 48 (0).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:52:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:52:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 48 (0).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:65:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:65:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 48 (0).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:73:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:73:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 48 (0).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:92:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:92:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:102:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:102:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:120:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:120:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:128:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:128:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:136:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:136:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:149:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:149:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:157:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:661:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:661:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 55 (7).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:680:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:680:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 56 (8).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:690:Junk character 49 (1).
/Users/mac/Desktop/Cannon Boy/Libraries/Assembly-UnityScript.dll.s:2929:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 95 (_).
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After hours of debugging I found out one of my scripts in Unity was starting with a number.
Renaming the script solved the problem!